# aws acm import-certificate throws LimitExceededException

Tags: aws-certificate-manager

I used to import a certificate into AWS Certificate Manager automatically by a bash script every week. This worked pretty well until some weeks ago. It started to fail with following exception:

```
An error occurred (LimitExceededException) when calling the ImportCertificate operation: You have imported the maximum number of 20 certificates in the last year.
```

I couldn't find much help by googling this issue. Do I have to increase any AWS limit? Which one?

Here is some more information that could help:

How I import the certificate:

```
aws acm import-certificate --region eu-central-1 --certificate file:///etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/cert.pem --private-key file:///etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain/privkey.pem --certificate-chain file:///etc/letsencrypt/live/my.comain/chain.pem --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:<some-number>:certificate/<some-uuid>
```

The output of `aws acm list-certificates`:

```
{
    "CertificateSummaryList": [
        {
            "CertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:<some-number>:certificate/<some-uuid>",
            "DomainName": "my.domain"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the certificate that I imported 3 months ago. Now it has expired unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS resolved my issue. I finally posted a support request to increase the limit "Number of ACM certificates". Now I can successfully import new certificates. Hope this helps other folks.

Comment: What a strange limit to have ... thanks for your post!

Comment: Just curious, remember how long it took them to process your request? Been waiting 24 hours, which is a long time for a service quota increase request, but I guess it's not a common one such as EIPs.

Comment: Well, just took this comment for it to be applied :)

Comment: What new quota did you request? I choose 1000 to not have to worry about this again and they're making me jump through hoops.

Comment: I think I just requested 100 or so. Did you already get your quota?